# Python Method: Execute multiple IP's in one unit test? The best practise?

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

**Details**

For a larger unittest I need a method in Python this allows servers / switches / routers to call IP's and respond accordingly to the test.

My thoughts in this regard:

- Reading out the IP's from a CSV file
- Create a configuration file in which I enter all relevant data.

**Setup**

> ```
> import testcore
> from testcore.control.ssh import SSH
> import unittest
> from test import support
> import logging
> import os
> ```

**Test Setup**

```
    def setUp(self):

    self.s = testcore.control.ssh.SSH(host='172.23.56.xxx',
                                  username='admin', password='admin', type_of_dut='ecos')
    logger.info('self.s = testcore.control.ssh.SSH')
    self.s.query_interactive=True


    if self.s.login():
        logger.info('login')
        q = self.s.query('account')
        logger.info('account')
        self.assertIsNotNone(q, 'missing answer')
        self.assertEqual('\r\n', q, 'unexpected result')
        logger.info('missing answer')
        logger.info('unexpected result')

        # switch to prompt account

        q=self.s.query('enforce-Password-Rules yes')
        logger.info('enforce-Password-Rules yes')
        q=self.s.query('exit')
        logger.info('exit')

        def tearDown(self):
        self.s.close()
```

**So what I need:**

How can I write a method in Python that allows me to run multiple IP's for my test?

Is this worth a configuration script?

**In this example, you'll see a test I'm running.**

```
def test_create_ntp_external1(self):
    logger_true.info('test_create_ntp_external1')
    if self.s.loggedin:
        logger.info('self.s.loggedin')
        q = self.s.query('time')
        logger.info('time')
        self.assertIsNotNone(q, 'missing answer')
        self.assertEqual('\r\n', q, 'unexpected result')
        logger.info('missing answer')
        logger.info('unexpected result')

        # switch to prompt account

        q = self.s.query('ntp 1 2610:20:6F15:15::27')
        logger.info('ntp 1 2610:20:6F15:15::27')
        print(q)
        q = self.s.query('exit')
        self.assertIsNotNone(q, 'missing answer')
        self.assertEqual('\r\n', q, 'unexpected result')
        logger.info('missing answer')
        logger.info('unexpected result')

        q = self.s.query('logout')
        logger.info('logout')

        import time
        print('Wait')
        time.sleep(2)
        print('True')
        logger_true.info('True')
```

The individual tests are called via the setup above but just according to one device at a time. So how is it possible to extend this so that I can call various IP's at the same time?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with UnitTest? What problem are you trying to solve (monitoring some infrastructure maybe?)

Comment: Is implemented this way, and can not be changed without much effort, to Pytest or other options.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you basically want to parameterise your tests with the IP, effectively creating new `testcore.control.ssh.SSH(host='172.23.56.xxx')` instances for each test?